# Spring Data Rest: Security based projection

Tags: spring-security, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am using the current version of [Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) and [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) and have following entity:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
   ...getter/setter methods...
}
```

I am also using `Spring Security`.

My User Repository:

```
   @RepositoryRestResource(
     collectionResourceRel = "user", 
     path = "user", 
    excerptProjection = UserSimpleProjection.class)
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

**For Example:**

- User 1 is logged in
- User 1 requests `http://localhost:8080/user/1` - all fields are visible
- User 1 requests `http://localhost:8080/user/2` - just `id` and `name` are visible.

I tried different solutions with Jackson, none of them solved my problem:

- Use of [JsonView](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews): I found no way, to change the view for the `ObjectMapper` depending on the logged in User
- Implemented different Jackson Filters as described [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) with the same issue that I found no way to change the `ObjectMapper` config for the different requests.

Then I found [Projections](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra#projections-in-spring-data-rest).

**I created a projection:**

```
@Projection(name = "simple", types = User.class)
public interface UserSimpleProjection {

    public Long getId();

    public String getName();
}
```

and another detailed one:

```
@Projection(name = "detailed", types = User.class)
public interface UserDetailProjection extends UserSimpleProjection{

    public String getEmail();
}
```

So far so good, I get different results depending on my request.

Is there a way to automatically switch the projection depending on Spring Security and/or limit different Projections for different roles?

Comment: Did you by any chance manage to make projections role based ?

Comment: No, I am sorry. I gave up back then and made custom controllers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add a "virtual" value property into the projection that invoke a service method with security checks:

```
@Projection(name = "detailed", types = User.class)
public interface UserDetailProjection extends UserSimpleProjection{

    @Value("#{@userService.checkAccess(target)? target.email : null}")
    public String getEmail();
}
```

Where your custom `UserService` component would return `true` if email should be exposed or simply has `@PreAuthorize` on `checkAccess(..)` to throw an `AccessDeniedException` whatever is better for you.

Note, the `target` property in the SpEL holds the original object - provided by Spring-DATA.

Comment: why is this not working @Value("#{principal.username.equalsIgnoreCase('admin') ? target.password : null}")

Comment: Because `principal` is not a property of the SpEL root object used in this context. To access a bean you can use `@` prefix. Pls read more about SpEL: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: Note, in SPeL you can use variables (`#myvar`), beans (`@mybean`), "root object" properties and methods, etc. Note also that expressions have different "root object" in different contexts that is set by some handler. E.g. `@PreAuthorize` handled by `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, and projection `@Value` - by `SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory`. You can check the source code for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using a [RegexRequestMatcher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RegexRequestMatcher.html) in your Spring Security config like this:

```
.regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/user/.*projection=simple.*").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Spring Data REST projections don't support this.