# How to restrict access by role to a Spring Data REST projection?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In an application using Spring Data JPA and Spring Data REST, let's say you have an entity class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   private String name;

   @JsonIgnore
   private String superSecretValue;

   ...

}
```

We want Spring Data REST to expose all of this entity's fields EXCEPT for `superSecretValue`, and so we've annotated that field with `@JsonIgnore`.

However, in some cases we DO want access to `superSecretValue`, and so we create a projection that will return all of the fields including that one:

```
@Projection(name = "withSecret", types = {Person.class})
public interface PersonWithSecret {

   String getName();
   String getSuperSecretValue();

}
```

Awesome.  So now we can access `Person` entities *including* the `superSecretValue` field like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/persons?projection=withSecret
```

My question is **how can we secure that *projection***?  How can we configure things such that anyone can retrieve `Person` entities *without* the `superSecretValue` field... but only people with a certain role (say, `ROLE_ADMIN`) can use the projection to retrieve the hidden field?

I've found endless examples of using `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` annotations to secure Spring Data JPA repository CRUD methods (e.g. `save()`, `delete()`)... but no examples of how to restrict usage of a Spring Data REST projection.

Comment: The question has been asked before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794145/spring-data-rest-security-based-projection - I think what you try to do is not supported. Also I would question if you should do it - a projection is just a different view on the data and bringing in security here does not sound right. I would go and implement a custom controller method for this and secure this one.

Comment: @MathiasDpunkt:  Let's say that you did write a custom controller method... with a return type of `Person`, and the `@ResponseBody` annotation applied to make it serialize to JSON.  In this case, the `superSecretValue` field will still be omitted due to the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.  So would you manually convert the `Person` entity to a basically-identical DTO class *without* `@JsonIgnore` on that field?  Would you implement your own custom Jackson serializer, and build the JSON yourself rather than rely on `@ResponseBody`?  Another approach?

Comment: @MathiasDpunkt:  It seems like it would HAVE to be a not-too-unusual use case to need role-based visibility on certain fields.  Granting role-based access to repository CRUD methods is so simple, it's rather bizarre that granting role-based visibility of entity fields is so cumbersome.  Just trying to figure out the path of least resistance.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I do not think that there is something wrong with the requirement you have. But I think that the way you try to model it could need some consideration. If the `superSecretValue` so different in terms of security than the other person attributes than it might not belong to the person at all. What if you model this value as a separate entity. Then you could provide a separate repository with the appropriate authorization rules and only the authorized users could traverse the relationship from person to the secret value.

Comment: Oh, I'm embarrassed that I didn't think of that.  A `@OneToOne` surrogate entity, with a different access level.  That's not 100% ideal, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload properties in projections using `@Value` with conditional SpEL expressions - as in this [already answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794145/spring-data-rest-security-based-projection/35399030#35399030).

Consider other alternatives (others already mentioned):

1. Model refactoring. Split entity by access logic (e.g. `Person` <-> `Account`)
2. Adding custom endpoints for special logic and access checks. For example, the current user at "/people/me".
3. Customising standard endpoints. For example, add custom controller for "/people", "/people/{id}" that would preprocess and return custom `Resource` type (DTO) depending on  on user authorities (e.g. returning `PublicPerson` instead `Person`). Then you can write custom resource processors for adding custom links and custom projections for these types.

See also: issue on this subject from spring-data-rest [DATAREST-428](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-428).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399030/679240

```
@Projection(name = "detailed", types = User.class)
public interface UserDetailProjection extends UserSimpleProjection{

    @Value("#{@userService.checkAccess(target)? target.email : null}")
    public String getEmail();
}
```