# Spring Data Rest - Use Projections based on role

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I just read through the Spring Data Rest documentation, but could not find any way to address the following issue.

Our rest endpoint should show more or less data, based on the current user access rights.

For example, if we have a Person class, a guest user can only see the firstname and lastname, but an admin user can also see the email address, street, city, etc...

Is there a way to bind Projections using Spring Security?

Comment: Here is another question regarding security and projections. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661815/how-to-restrict-access-by-role-to-a-spring-data-rest-projection I do not think you can implement what you want using projections

Comment: Thanks. I just read it, but that's not really an answer. Would it be possible to create a role-conditional @JsonIgnore variation? Like @JsonInclude(has_role('ROLE_USER_ADMIN')) or similar? Doesn't need to be a projection, but a way to control the output fields more easily and manageable long term.