# Control JSON data with Spring Security

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a class named Order shown below.

```
    class Order{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    //getters and setters
    }
```

Using Spring security, I need to be able to control the data that is being returned as a response from Spring Controller. For say, Admin can view all the data of Order, but customer can see only name and amount. How can I filter the JSON data with Spring Security.So, final output for admin should be

```
     [{id:1,name:order1,amount:100}, {id:2,name:order2,amount:200}]
```

and output for customer should be

```
    [{name:order1,amount:100}, {name:order2,amount:200}].
```

Is there any way to do this

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794145/spring-data-rest-security-based-projection

Comment: I want to control the JSON data instead of DB query. And I am using Hibernate Criteria for querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

you could hack it a bit with Spring Data and Spring Security:

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {

    @Query(
            value = "select id, amount, case when ?#{hasRole('admin')} then name else null end as name from foo where id=?1",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    Foo findOne(Long id);
}
```

You'd need to add an EvaluationContextExtensionSupport bean. This lets you use Spring Security expressions in Spring Data queries:

```
@Component
public class MyEvaluationContextExtensionSupport extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport{

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};

    }
}
```

Or you could try [Projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) with Spring Data REST

```
//untested:
@Projection(name = "detailed", types = Foo.class)
public interface FooDetailProjection {

    @Value("?#{ hasRole('admin')? target.name: null}")
    public String getName();
}
```

Or consider using [Column Security](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) directly in your database.

Comment: Hi, Could you please explain more about the 2nd method i.e EvaluationContextExtensionSupport .

Comment: @Raghavendra that just lets you put spring security expressions into spring data queries