# How to secure association resources?

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest

The problem can be defined by the following example:

I have a class `MainClass` which is related with another class called `AssociatedClass` by a `@OneToOne` relation. Both have an exposed Repository so I can do a GET on the URL `/mainClasses/{some_id}` and on the URL `/associatedClasses/{some_id}`. However, the `AssociatedClassRepository` has the following code:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AssociatedClassRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AssociatedClass, String> {
    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("1 == 2")
    AssociatedClass findOne(String s);
}
```

So it will never authorize the GET method to an object of type `AssociatedClass`. However, as the object of type `MainClass` has an `AssociatedClass` object associated, I can obtain this object by doing a GET at `/mainClasses/{some_id}/associatedClass`.

I would like to block the access to `/mainClasses/{some_id}/associatedClass` but not for all the users. I'd like to define some condition in the same way I can do it through `@PreCondition`. So that I can allow the access only if the authenticated user is the owner of the resource, which is my real goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your controller code? and repository code?

Comment: I don't have any controller because I'm using Spring Data Rest. I have edited the post so that you can see the full code of the AssociatedClassRepository.

Comment: This rather looks to me like security is not activated at all. Spring Data REST is basically just invoking the method. If that doesn't trigger a security exception, your Spring Security setup seems to be incorrect. Are you sure you have method security activated?

Comment: If I perform a GET on the URL `/associatedClasses/{some_id}` the response will always be a `403 Forbidden`. So the `@PreAuthorize` is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to secure Spring Data REST endpoints at the URL level. For example:

```
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/entity/{[0-9]+}/{[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+}").hasRole("ADMIN").
           and().csrf().disable();
            }
        }
```

Public access:

- /entities
- /entities/entityId

Admin access:

- /entities/entityId/associated entity

Comment: This will work for most of the cases. Unfortunately, in my case I need to secure the resources based on whether the logged user is the owner of it or not.

Comment: For example, in my user class I have annotated with `@PreAuthorize("principal.id == #id")` the `findOne` method. And I have another class ("CreatedEntity") which is related with the user who is the owner/creator of each object. So the problem will be on the URL `/createdEntities/id/createdBy`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply an excerpt projection to the associated entity's repository and add there security checks as described in

[Spring Data Rest: Security based projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794145/spring-data-rest-security-based-projection)

The associated resource will be returned but you can hide certain fields or all of them.