# Spring Data Rest: How to secure findById() but not for projections?

Tags: security, spring-security, repository, spring-data-rest, projection

I'm using Spring-Data-Rest and I want to secure the GET-Request of an entity only if one does **not** request a projection (since the projections hide all the sensible stuff). e.g.:

```java
public interface UsergroupRepository extends OwnableRepository<User> {
    @PostAuthorize("@userService.isMe(returnObject)")
    Optional<Usergroup> findById(Long id);
}
```

But this rule forbids the access to the projections, too. So what can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794145/spring-data-rest-security-based-projection

Comment: Spring Security is protecting methods. I see only one method in your interface. If you have a second method, show that method. Is it in your `OwnableRepository` interface?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface UsergroupRepository extends OwnableRepository<User> {
    @PostAuthorize("@userService.isMe(returnObject)")
    Optional<User> findById(Long id);

    Optional<UserProjection> findByIdWithProjection(Long id);
}
```

Do not add `@Projection` to the projection interface. Users don't need to know about it.

The only drawback is that the other endpoint will be different: `/users/search/findByIdWithProjection`
(However you can rename the endpoint with the `@RestResource`)